# Formatting CSV values from a file in Javascript to populate Google Chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, csv, google-visualization

I have a CSV file with values like `date value1 value2` . I want to populate Google charts with this data. Using jquery-csv.js , I'm reading the values.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.csv.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

  // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
  google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});

  // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  // Callback that creates and populates a data table,
  // instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and
  // draws it.
  function drawChart() {
   $.get("data.csv", function(csvString) {
      // transform the CSV string into a 2-dimensional array
      var arrayData = $.csv.toArrays(csvString, {onParseValue: $.csv.hooks.castToScalar});
//alert(arrayData);
      // this new DataTable object holds all the data
      var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(arrayData);
      alert(data.getColumnLabel(0));
//Here I alert like 06/11/201522 
The usual google chart code follows
});
      }
    </script>
```

When I alert data.getColumnLabel(0) , I get all the values of the first row combined. How do I split it? I want each column data in a separate variable. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I don't what's your data contains. Assuming it contains `date value1 value2` , you can use `data.getColumnLabel(0).split(" ")[0]` to get `date` and `data.getColumnLabel(0).split(" ")[1]` to get `value1` and `data.getColumnLabel(0).split(" ")[2]` to get `value2`

Comment: I'm getting everything together. No spaces in between the values..

Comment: Like 06/11/201522 (date,value1 and value2 together without spaces)

Comment: Well i don't know how you can pull these 3 values if you don't have a separator. Are you able to modify your csv file ?

Comment: In CSV, everything is already in seperate cells. How do you want me to change it?

Comment: your code works for me, are you sure you have correct csv format? open the csv file in notepad or text editor and make sure each cell is separated by a comma

Comment: Sounds like a CSV formatting issue. It's worth noting that CSV is a format without any real standard. That's why most CSV import tools have dozens of options. I would make sure what you have, at the very least has commas between the values. It might also be helpful to mention what is producing your CSV. Excel, a database engine, some third-party service, etc.

Comment: Hi. I opened the CSV in Notepad, and you guys are right. Its not separated by comma. This is the first time I'm working with a CSV file. Let me try to create a proper CSV file. Thank you all for the help.